# What is Remote iCloud Backup?

Tags: icloud, backup

It was listed on a slide in the iOS 11 keynote. What does it do and how does it work? My best guess is that I can initiate an iCloud backup by signing into iCloud online?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWTL1.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly looks like that. However, there seems no way to trigger it yet (maybe it will be added to a iOS 11.x future update).

There's no trace of it on iCloud.com but something appears if look up another device in iOS > Settings > *Apple ID* (top) > *Another Device* (Bottom)

In my case it only shows `-` and inaccurately says `Last iCloud Backup: Never` so it looks like it's not fully supported yet

[image: A secondary device (iPad) as it appears from another device (iPhone)]